# What is the distribution of eigenvalues of $A^TA$, where $A \sim N(\mu, \Sigma)$?

Tags: random-matrices, eigenvalues

Let $A$ be a random matrix following multivariate normal distribution $N(\mu, \Sigma)$.

> What is the distribution of the eigenvalues of $A^TA$?

A reference to the literature would be most welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unlike in the case $\mu=0$, $\Sigma=I$, there is no simple closed-form expression for the eigenvalue distribution. In the limit of large matrices the eigenvalue density follows from the Pastur equation, see [Spectral density of the non-central correlated Wishart ensembles](https://arxiv.org/abs/1406.4184) (section VI and figure 2).

The nonzero $\mu$ is a rank-one perturbation, which leaves the main spectrum unaffected but causes a single eigenvalue to separate from the spectrum, see [Eigenvalue separation in some random matrix models.](https://arxiv.org/abs/0810.1554)